# RegEx to find ASCII chars

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a string like this-

"CRT\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00G3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x10a\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16@E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13"

I have to convert ASCII chars(CRT, G3, a, @E) to HEX and other chars \x00 to \x09 will be replaced by 0 to 9 respectively and \x10 above will be shown as 10 and above respectively.

So what I am trying to do is to write a RegEx to find a char which does not match the pattern **/\x../g** and convert those chars to hex and replace the ascii by the hex and then I can handle \x.. pattern with another regEx.

The pattern I have written is **/[^\x\d\d]|[^\x\w\d]|[^\x\d\w]/g**

Here is my regex pattern and the string on regex101.com- [MyRegEx](https://regex101.com/r/zyeaZm/1)

If you see thing are working as expected other than one issue. Issue- I am not getting 3 as matched which is after G (G3).

Can someone help on this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try [`\\x.{2}(*SKIP)(*F)|.`](https://regex101.com/r/fyecD6/1) if you are working in PHP. Or [`\\x.{2}(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?!\\x.{2}).)+`](https://regex101.com/r/fyecD6/2).

Comment: Your regex uses character classes incorrectly. A character class is a bracketed set of characters (or other classes). You're using strings - `\x` - inside it in an incorrect way. [See this example](https://regex101.com/r/57Phg8/1) and check the explanation on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like

```
(?!\\x\d\d)(.)|..(..)
```

This captures single ASCII character into group 1 and the HEX-sequences int o group 2.

If group 1 isn't empty it should be converted to a two digit HEX code and inserted. Otherwise the second group should be inserted ().

[See an attempt to illustrate it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zyeaZm/3).

Comment: this is what i was looking for. I changed it a little and now It served my purpose. Thanks. :)